# Create a Windows C# App that can open up applications

Tags: c#

I recently had this idea to create a C# Windows Form App that enables a user to launch applications from there. This is my 'raw' code:

Button1 Click Event...

```
{                     

 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE");

}
```

Button2 Click Event...

```
{

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("WINRAR.EXE");

}
```

.
.
.
.
.
.

and many more ...

Can anyone please tell me what the code is in case that handles the event in case that an application cannot be found(ex. WINWORD.EXE is not available blah, blah blah)?

I tried using the 'if-statement' but to no avail, I get compilation errors.

Can someone help me out? How can I create a function that lets the user add some application shortcut to the C# app?

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: What compilation errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just put your call to launch the app into a `try...catch...` block

Button2 Click Event...

```
{
   try 
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("WINRAR.EXE");
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
       // handle exception, e.g. possibly log it to a file or database, or do something else
       MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   }
}
```

In this case, no matter what goes wrong, you'll be able to catch that case and at least show a message to the user - of course, you might want to "tweak" that message a bit .....

Answer (score 3):

```
System.IO.File.Exists("your file path");
```

returns true if file exits

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists("your file path"))
{
          //Do something
}
else
{
           OpenFileDialog _File = new OpenFileDialog())           
           _File.ShowDialog(); // this will open a filedialog box to browse 
}
```

Comment: But in this case - you first need to figure out the proper and complete path where your EXE file lives....

Comment: does this requires me to provide the FULL PATH of an application? And, considering your suggestion...

if(System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Users\ProgramFiles\WinRAR\Winrar.exe
{
  //WHAT SHOULD BE IN HERE? RUN?, OPEN?
}
else
{
 MessageBox.Show("File could not be found");
}


in case that the file is missing, how can I provide the users the option to delete the button or manually browse for it? Thanks for you effort! :)

Comment: oh, my bad. sorry for the BAD INDENT IONS I made.

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.IO.File.Exists` to verify the file path or use `try..catch..` block to handle the exceptions.

```
try
{
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE");
}catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: try
{
   //do i now place the "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start" code block here?
}catch(Exception ex)
{

}

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to "look before you leap" and check the system's `PATH` and the system registry for the file - but this is much harder than it might seem. On my PC, for instance, Microsoft Office is not found through the path.

Simplest is to check for `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`:

```
try
{
    Process.Start("filename.exe");
}
catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.NativeErrorCode == 2)
    {
         // file was not found, so do something
    }
}
```

By explicitly checking for the correct underlying exception you ensure your system still stops if something happens other than the file-not-found situation. Also, by checking for error code 2, you know your system should work on versions of Windows using languages other than English.